# How to authenticate Gmail API from Google Compute Engine?

Tags: gmail, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to write a simple Python script (running from GCE) which sends regular reminder emails from my GMail account. It *sounded like* I can just use the default service account that is created with the GCE VM to authenticate the service.

I enabled G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation on the default service account and then instantiated the service by:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.auth import compute_engine

def instantiate_service():
  SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']
  credentials = compute_engine.Credentials(scopes=SCOPES)

  service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

  return service
```

However, when I use this service to actually send the message, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

I don't think I'm understanding something about how to properly authorize GMail from within a GCE environment, and I find the documentation pretty hard to sift through. Can someone help set me straight?

Comment: Can you share the documentation that you are following?

Answer (score 0):

I see that in the variable `SCOPES` you have defined the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send`, which may be insufficient for sending drafts (I think that you may be missing the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose` scope)

Try to add it in the variable and check if it works. If not, I would recommend to
change it for `https://mail.google.com/` and check if it works. Then, try to narrow down the gmail scopes following the reference [1].

Also don't forget to remove the credentials stored in the `credentials.json` file in order to get a new one.

Just FYI, I looked at this sample [2] to check how it does work, you may find some interesting information there.

I hope this approach helps you!

---

[1] https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes

[2] https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample